# How to manage data in a database when the data is of indeterminate size?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm looking to build a database to store the name of students in the surrounding schools. I'm currently thinking one table of all of the schools and then it would seem the next logical step is a table for each school, the problem is that I don't know how many schools I'm going to need to do. It's easily more than 200 and it looks like I'm going to end up with a database with hundreds of tables. Is it ok to design a database where you make a new table for each entry?

Furthermore, how do you go about handling something where people have to submit responses but the responses can vary quite a bit by length. Like when you're dealing with someone's email address it seems like a waste to allot 500 chars per address but at the same time, you know there's definitely an email out there that's 100 chars. Do you cater to your worst case or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a one-to-many relationship with two tables:

**school**

- id
- name
- ...

**student**

- id
- schoolID
- nameFirst
- nameLast
- email
- ...

Then a query like this would work:

```
SELECT school.name, student.nameFirst, student.nameLast, student.email
FROM student
INNER JOIN school ON student.schoolID = school.id;
```

If one student can attend multiple schools, you will need a junction table:

**school**

- id
- name
- ...

**student**

- id
- nameFirst
- nameLast
- email
- ...

**studentSchool**

- studentID
- schoolID

The third table is a junction table that facilitates a many-to-many relationship. Many students may attend zero, one, or more schools. A query like this would then work:

```
SELECT school.name, student.nameFirst, student.nameLast, student.email
FROM studentSchool
INNER JOIN school ON studentSchool.schoolID = school.id
INNER JOIN student ON studentSchool.studentID = student.id;
```

With regard to field length, in most cases MySQL uses dynamic row sizes so that there is no wasted space. If you do VARCHAR(255), you can store up to 255 characters, but it will only require the minimum storage space (plus some small overhead) to store your value. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Ahhh that makes a lot of sense. Ok so one more question. For each student lets say they can go to more than one school. There's no limit to how many they can attend and I don't know the worst case. How do I cope with that?

Comment: I updated the answer to include information about many-to-many relationships, which I believe addresses your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to build a database to store the name of students in the surrounding schools. I'm currently thinking one table of all of the schools and then it would seem the next logical step is a table for each school, the problem is that I don't know how many schools I'm going to need to do.

Half right: one table with all the schools (and relevant information about them). That table will have a primary key -- an auto incrementing integer would be okay.

Then have a table of students with a [Foreign Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) column that contains the ID of the school which the student attends.

Only two tables: one for schools and one for students. Related with a foreign key. Or, optionally, if a student can go to more than one school, a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) would be necessary.

> Do you cater to your worst case or is there a way around this?

Yes. You want your application to work for everyone, so make it work for everyone.